# Magento 2 Popup Modal give errors into the iphone(safari)

Tags: magento2.3.2, popup, modal-popup, modal, iphone

I am using the Magento 2.3.2 Version.

I have set the popup modal but it is not working into the iPhone safari browser. They give the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'elem.nodeName'

Please check below my popup modal code

```
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'owlslider'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            buttons: []
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal')); //This line Gives error
        $(".country_switcher").on('click',function(){
            $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
        });
    });
```

Please give me the solution how to solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Hardik you have solved this problem using below ways

1) By putting your model code inside `$( document ).ready()`

2) Check the length of your div whether you declared div is available or not.

Try the below code.

```
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'owlslider'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            buttons: []
        };

        $(document).ready(function(){     
        $(".country_switcher").on('click',function(){ 
            if ($('#popup-mpdal').length != 0) {  
            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            }                                
        });
      });
```

Comment: IT WORKS FOR ME +1

Comment: This Solution worked for me